# Angular Interface: use brackets in label name

Tags: angular, label

I am trying to create an Interface with labels that contain brackets like this:

```
export interface Interface{
    label1: number;
    label(test): number;
}
```

How could i use brackets in the label name?

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to add quote around the property:

```js
export interface Interface{
  label1: number;
  'label(test)': number;
}
```